# Get entire certificate using Perl's Net::SSLeay

Tags: perl, ssl, certificate

I want to use the Perl library [`Net::SSLeay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSLeay) to download a server's SSL certificate but am having trouble figuring out how to do this. I want the *entire* certificate, not just the common name and a few of the fields.

For example, I would give the script the argument `google.com` and it would connect to https://google.com and get the entire certificate string for the certificate with CN "*.google.com".

This script needs to run on a Debian wheezy server so must use version 1.48 of `Net::SSLeay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this might be what you want?

```
($reply, $err, $cert) = sslcat('www.google.com', 443, '/'); # 5
$PEM = Net::SSLeay::PEM_get_string_X509( $cert);
```

Will give you the PEM encoded SSL certificate. You can decode it using MIME::Base64.